# Updating JTable row dynamically after the deletion successive rows

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency, jtable

I have a JTable and I am inserting rows to that JTable dynamically. 
After some user intervention, a new row will be inserted .Then I will call a function with parameter as selected row number and inside that function, I have some code which will update the same row accordingly. Each row insertion and row value update code will run in a separate thread.

```
public void updateRow(int row,JTable myTable)
{
  String text = "";
 //After lot of processing, setting the table cell value at the 'row' on the 4th column
  myTable.setValueAt(text, row, 4);
}
```

The issue I am facing is as follows,

If the user deleting any row, then row's position will change and at that time if the function `updateRow()` trying to update some other row, then it will fail because of change of row count.

Lets say I have 3 row at a time and each row's updateRow is in progress.

```
updateRow(0,userTable);//For the 1st row
updateRow(1,userTable);//For the 2nd row
updateRow(2,userTable);//For the 3rd row
```

and assume 2nd row's updateRow() is completed. This will cause issue in updateRow() function of 3rd row. Because, it has the row value as '2' . Since the 3rd row got deleted, there is no 3rd row and which in turn cause the following code to fail

```
myTable.setValueAt(text, row, 4);//Currently, row has the value as '2'
```

Can anyone suggest me how can I keep track of the row update with row values accordingly, even if the row's position got changed dynamically ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Each row insertion and row value update code will run in a separate thread"* - That is an incredibly bad idea.  Swing is not thread safe and you are expected to update the UI only from the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Comment: Do you have any data in the row that can uniquely identify the row? If so then you can save that identifier. Then when it comes time to update the row you search the table the find the current row for the identifier.

Comment: `Each row insertion and row value update code will run in a separate thread`, right then Thread or row doesn't exists, depends of direction, use AbstractTableModel based on util.List, row index is only decreasing, easiest of ways is to use unique ID as suggested @camickr, then doesn't matter if one row is added or deleted nor modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of relying on the view's row number, operate on the model directly, as suggested in a comment by @mKorbel; if you alter the model, the view will follow. As discussed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), "`JTable` provides methods that convert from model coordinates to view coordinates — `convertColumnIndexToView` and `convertRowIndexToView` — and that convert from view coordinates to model coordinates — `convertColumnIndexToModel` and `convertRowIndexToModel`.

Comment: trashgod, Anyway it will return the correct index when it is sorted right? But here, in my case, I am not sorting the data. Few row items can be removed at any time

Comment: Yes, the conversion methods are available even if you're _not_ sorting. If you need to mutate the model from another thread, wrap the call in `invokeLaer()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3671909/230513).