# Wrong index when select rows in JTable

Tags: java, swing, select, jtable

I have a popup menu to delete multiple rows in `JTable`.
This table has a column with boolean value (true/false). if value of this column is true, will delete this row.
But indexes array was selected is wrong. 
Example: select rows with indexes are 2,3,4 but the result is 0,2,3. The first row was always selected. 
If select multiple rows without condition, result is correct.

Anyone can help me?

this is sample code (using Netbeans):

```
private void menuDeleteLOANActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        int[] rows = this.tabMAIN.getSelectedRows();
        try {           
            for(int i = rows.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
                boolean temp = ((Boolean)this.tabMAIN.getValueAt(i, 8)).booleanValue();
                if(temp == true){
                    System.out.println("ID "+this.tabMAIN.getValueAt(i, 3)+((Boolean)this.tabMAIN.getValueAt(i, 8)).booleanValue());
                }else{
                     System.out.println("ID "+this.tabMAIN.getValueAt(i, 3)+((Boolean)this.tabMAIN.getValueAt(i, 8)).booleanValue());
                }
             }          
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: You may be confounding view and model coordinates, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15543732/230513).

Answer (score 2):

You are not accessing the values of the array. This should me more correct:

```
private void menuDeleteLOANActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        int[] rows = this.tabMAIN.getSelectedRows();
        try {           
            for(int i = rows.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
                boolean temp = ((Boolean)this.tabMAIN.getValueAt(rows[i], 8)).booleanValue();
                if(temp == true){
                    System.out.println("ID "+this.tabMAIN.getValueAt(rows[i], 3)+((Boolean)this.tabMAIN.getValueAt(rows[i], 8)).booleanValue());
                }else{
                     System.out.println("ID "+this.tabMAIN.getValueAt(rows[i], 3)+((Boolean)this.tabMAIN.getValueAt(rows[i], 8)).booleanValue());
                }
             }          
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try by converting row index to model index

```
 for (int z = 0; z < tblQue1.getRowCount();) {

                if ((Boolean) tblQue1.getValueAt(z, 4) == true) {

                    dmQue1.removeRow(tblQue1.convertRowIndexToModel(z));
                } else {
                    z++;
                }
            }
```