# Invoking setValueAt doesn't send a TableModel Event

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I wrote a personal `TableModel` that takes data from db.
The problem is when I modify data in the table , I could see the effect 
on the table but no table event succeds. It seems like the method 
`setValueAt` doesn't make an event, but I can see he update the cell of table.
Obviusly I add in the main program these codes.

i added these to show that it doesnt work

Stabili.java (the sourceof data from db)

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(catalog = "", schema = "ROOT")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Stabili.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Stabili s"),})
public class Stabili implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(nullable = false)
private Long id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
private String indirizzo;

public Stabili() {
}

public Stabili(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getIndirizzo() {
    return indirizzo;
}

public void setIndirizzo(String indirizzo) {
    this.indirizzo = indirizzo;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (!(object instanceof Stabili)) {
        return false;
    }
    Stabili other = (Stabili) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "entity.Stabili[ id=" + id + " ]";
}
}
```

// the tablemodel StabiliTableModel.java

```
package prova;

import entity.Stabili;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class StabiliTableModel implements TableModel, TableModelListener{

protected EventListenerList listenerList = new EventListenerList();
private final EntityManager em;
private final TypedQuery<Stabili> qry;
private final List<Stabili> results;

public StabiliTableModel(EntityManager em){
    this.em = em;
    qry = em.createNamedQuery("Stabili.findAll",Stabili.class);
    results = qry.getResultList();
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return results.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
    switch (columnIndex){
        case 0:
            return "Id";
        case 1:
            return "Indirizzo";
    }
}

@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    switch (columnIndex){
                case 0:
                    return results.get(rowIndex).getId();
                case 1:
                    return results.get(rowIndex).getIndirizzo();
    }
}

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    switch (columnIndex){
        case 1:
            results.get(rowIndex).setIndirizzo(aValue.toString());
    }
    fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex,columnIndex);
}

@Override
public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
}

@Override
public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
}

@Override
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.getColumn());
}

public void fireTableDataChanged(){
  fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this, 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
}
public void fireTableStructureChanged(){
   fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this, TableModelEvent.HEADER_ROW));
}

public void fireTableRowsInserted(int firstRow, int lastRow){
      fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this, firstRow, lastRow,
                                           TableModelEvent.ALL_COLUMNS,
                                           TableModelEvent.INSERT));
}

public void fireTableRowsUpdated(int firstRow, int lastRow){
    fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this, firstRow, lastRow,
                                       TableModelEvent.ALL_COLUMNS,
                                       TableModelEvent.UPDATE));
}


public void fireTableRowsDeleted(int firstRow, int lastRow)
{
  fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this, firstRow, lastRow,
                                       TableModelEvent.ALL_COLUMNS,
                                       TableModelEvent.DELETE));
}


public void fireTableCellUpdated(int row, int column)
{
  fireTableChanged(new TableModelEvent(this, row, row, column));
}

public void fireTableChanged(TableModelEvent event){
    int    index;
    TableModelListener listener;
    Object[] list = listenerList.getListenerList();
    for (index = 0; index < list.length; index += 2){
      listener = (TableModelListener) list [index + 1];
      listener.tableChanged(event);
    }
}
```

}

// and finally the main

```
package prova;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;
 import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;


public class Prova extends JFrame{

private JTable mainTable,fixedTable;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private JTableHeader mainTableHeader;
private TableColumnModel originalColumnModel,mainColumnModel,fixedColumnModel;
private TableColumn[] columns;
private int ncols,counter;
private EntityManager em;

public Prova(){

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("provaPU");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();

    StabiliTableModel mainTableModel = new StabiliTableModel(em);

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

    mainTable = new JTable(mainTableModel);

    mainTableModel.addTableModelListener(mainTableModel);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(mainTable);
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
@Override
        public void run() {
    new Prova().setVisible(true);
        }
});
}
}
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3671010/230513); extend `AbstractTableModel` and  fire the appropriate event in `setValueAt()`, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3671909/230513).

Comment: This is not duplicate !!!  The problem is that i dont WANT to extends AbtractTableModel, i need to implements TableModel. Yours is not an explanation cause i think the problem is setValueAt, i rewrote it but probabily there is not something that fire the event...but i dont know what..

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3671909/230513), the [preferred approach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) is to extend [`AbstractTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) and [fire](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#fire) a suitable `TableModelEvent` in your implementation of `setValueAt()`. `DefaultTableModel` is an example.

> I don't *want* to extend `AbtractTableModel`.

Some alternatives:

- Delegate to a subclass of `AbtractTableModel` in your `StabiliTableModel`.
- Add an instance of [`EventListenerList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) as a member of `StabiliTableModel` and fire your own events using the scheme outlined in the `EventListenerList` API.

> There is not something that fire the event, but I don't know what.

Exactly; you'll need to use the existing event mechanism or create your own.

Comment: Thanks for answer, could you make me an example of this - Delegate to a subclass of AbtractTableModel in your StabiliTableModel. OR Add an instance of EventListenerList as a member of StabiliTableModel and fire your own events using the scheme outlined in the EventListenerList API.

Comment: Her are some delegate [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=AbstractTableModel%20delegate); [tag:jfreechart] uses `EventListenerList` extensively in its datasets.

Comment: Unfortunally i cant resolve it. I tryed to change StabiliTableModel and make it extends AbstractTableModel but it doesnt work too.

Comment: To help isolate the problem, please edit your question to include a [complete, self-contained example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that focuses on the table and exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Your implementation of `setValueAt()` should fire the appropriate event, for [example](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.java#l652).